# How to list all new files added or deleted in git repo from last one week commits

Tags: git, gitlab

I am not too much familiar with git commands. Is there a way to list only newly added or deleted files in git in last one week?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`--diff-filter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203) and show added files (A) & deleted files (D) between your working tree & a specific commit :

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AD  <commit sha>
```

You can also get the oldest commit sha since 7 days using :

```
git log --reverse --since=7.days --format="%H" | head -1
```

So you can endup with the following to list added & deleted files since 7 days :

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AD $(git log --reverse --since=7.days --format="%H" | head -1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this works perfect! Is there a way I can limit it to display the files only from last 7 days or something?

Comment: @user360 I've updated my answer for using git log to find the oldest commit since 7 days